# Weird crash when iOS device is idle?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm building an app that uses Core Data, and everything works great, except for one thing. If I let the app sit idly, it suddenly throws a SIGTRAP error with no debugging prompt and no hint as to why it did so.

I suspect that it has to do with when the device automatically saves to it's UIManagedDocument seeing as that's the only function that would run in the background on it's own. Assuming that it is, does anyone have any ideas on how I could at least find out what is going on?

**EDIT:**

After learning what exception breakpoints were (lol), I've got the following errorstack in NSManagedObjectContext Queue: 0_cxa_begin_catch.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and see where it crashes. It will give you a stack frame there. To add an exception breakpoint, go to the breakpoint window and press on the left bottom + sign and add Exception breakpoint. Atleast that will give you some more information and will break exactly where the error is occuring instead of you second guessing.

Comment: Of course I could, but where can I put a breakpoint for something that doesn't occur until the app is entirely loaded up and functional? The crash happens as randomly and suddenly as you could imagine...

Comment: That is the whole point, you do not need to set the breakpoint. The system will set up a break point where there is exception. Try it out and you will love it.

Comment: Wow... All the time I've wasted trying to guess breakpoints. You sir, have changed my life (because I'm an idiot)! Okay, the error catches an NSManagedObjectContextQueue: 0__cxa_begin_catch. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried committing changes immediately after updating to see if the issue occurs instead of relying on the auto save feature?

Comment: Yes, it didn't affect anything.